# Having SetOptions[] affect CDF styling

Tags: cdf-format

Instead of writing a package and importing it, at the beginning of many of my .nb files I have a string of SetOptions commands which govern things like plot styling.  However, when I subsequently make a CDF based on elements using those options, the CDF doesn't incorporate them.  Is there an easy way to fix that?

```
SetOptions[Plot,
  AxesStyle -> Directive[25, Thickness[.005]], 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.005]},
  ImageSize -> 550
];
Manipulate[
  Plot[x^e, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
  {e, 0, 5}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Additionally why not just put the options directly into `Plot`?

Comment: The problem is that I usually have several plots in the Manipulate[.], so it gets very redundant.

Comment: The Initialization:> method didn't seem to work either (I stored the options as opts= and then did Initialization:>opts, and nothing :/)

Answer (score 2):

Three methods...

#### Initialization

Nasser's suggestion to put `SetOptions` in `Initialization` works for me:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[x^e, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
   Plot[Sin[e x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
   }],
 {e, 0, 5},
 Initialization :> (SetOptions[Plot, 
     AxesStyle -> Directive[25, Thickness[.005]], 
     PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.005]}, ImageSize -> 250];)
 ]
```

#### Use With to insert options

Here the options are stored in one place, so if you need to modify them, it's easy.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{myPlotOpts = {AxesStyle -> Directive[25, Thickness[.005]], 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.005]}, ImageSize -> 250}},
  Column[{
    Plot[x^e, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, myPlotOpts],
    Plot[Sin[e x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, myPlotOpts]
    }]
  ],
 {e, 0, 5}]
```

#### Using a custom Plot

The function `myPlot` adds the desired options to the arguments `args` passed to `Plot`.

```
SetAttributes[myPlot, HoldAll]
myPlot[args__] := Plot[args, AxesStyle -> Directive[25, Thickness[.005]], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.005]}, ImageSize -> 250];

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   myPlot[x^e, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
   myPlot[Sin[e x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
   }],
 {e, 0, 5},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

#### Output

All the outputs look the same.  (I changed the styling to make the differences more visually obvious.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### Additional considerations

The third method has the advantage that if there are several `Manipulate`s in the CDF, they all have the same styling.  With the first two, those methods would need to be repeated in each `Manipulate`.  (You cannot be sure that if `SetOptions` occurs in just one `Manipulate`, it will be executed before the other `Manipulate`s are updated.)  Also `SetOptions` affects the options globally.  They are stored in the Kernel.  So having it in one CDF will affect other CDFs that are open.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know what I've done that I thought it is not working. :)